# SSRS Get from page 2 to end page

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, render, python-2to3

I m rendering SSRS Report in pdf format. I want pages from 2 to Last page. Using deviceinfo is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve using device info with startpage as 2 and endpage as int.maxvalue